# How to set secret_key in GitPython

Tags: python, git, gitpython

How to set git secret-key to GitPython in order to access already cloned local repo

```
import git
repo = git.Repo('local/already-cloned-repo-path')
repo.remotes.origin.pull()
```

Consider the case where git credentials are not stored in ~/.gitconfig. (This usecase is when the above code ran inside a docker container. )
On git pull, it will ask for credentials. How to set username and secret-key to GitPython context?